# WINTER TIRES - I have winter tire set of 215/60/16 for my Camry 2007 I want to fixed for my Nissan Rouge SV with tire size 225/65/17

Tags: tires

I have winter tire set of 215/60/16 for my Camry 2007. I want to fixed in my car 
 Nissan  Rouge SV with tire size 225/65/17

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hi. It's not clear what you are asking.  Do you want to take the wheels and tires from the Camry and put them on the Nissan?

Answer (score 1):

16" tires will not fit on 17" rims...

Buy 16" rims for the Nissan, if they are available and fit the 16" winter tires on them.

If, however, 16" rims are not available for the Nissan, due to brake size etc, then buy some 17" winter tires.